# How do I pass the correct data type to Javascript from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery post method to create a record in MySQL. When I evaluate the output of the PHP with `==`, all three conditionals work properly. However, when I use `===`, the first two conditionals return `false`. How do I pass the correct data type to Javascript from PHP?

jQuery:

```
$("#form").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do other stuff for a valid form
        $.post('inc/process_form.php', $("#form").serialize(), function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#results').html("Success");
            } else if (data == 2) {
                $('#results').html("No Success");
            } else {
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is the PHP (which I've truncated to only show the execute conditional):

```
$value = $stmt->execute();

if ($value === TRUE) {
echo 1; //success
} else {
echo 2; //failure
}
```

Comment: For the general problem of passing data from your PHP script back to the javascript, you should look at PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and jQuery's [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). This duo lets you pass more complex data structures, and handles types (string, numeric, boolean) automatically. IMO, the simplicity offered makes it worthwhile even in simple cases like this where you're only passing one value.

Comment: reading the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post - it looks like `data` from `function(data) {...}` always returns as a string `dataType Type: String The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).`, so it looks like you cannot return an integer thus the `===` will always fail as `'1' !== 1`. You would need to do what @grossvogel suggests and return json encoded string and then parse it to get the integer type

Comment: To expand on @Sean's comment: if you're returning json from your PHP script, you can set that `dataType` parameter to 'json' and not even have to use `$.parseJSON()`. It'll parse automatically and `data` will be a nice javascript object with correctly-typed properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
if(parseInt(data) === 1){
```

The problem is the return variable `data` is a string, you can't do anything (as far as I know) from PHP to return it as a integer.

As the comment by Marc Costello suggested, this makes the `===` useless since you are forcing both sides to be integer, so `data == 1` is better in this case.

Comment: Just from the top of my head. But `die(1)` does this return a string?

Comment: This is correct, however parsing the string to int in this case may seem unnecessary. Try if (data == '1')

Comment: that's a good question, the PHP itself should return nothing (unless you echoed something before the die), but the exit status of the script will be 1, the exit status will be captured by a system call with 2 arguments, for example.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with PHP and its capabilities. PHP does indeed echo an integer out. However, it's the HTTP protocol here that transmits data and all the data transmitted over HTTP are strings. Period. That's why JSON or XML are used, if certain type-safety is required.

Comment: @N.B. yup and noone said otherwise. That's why I said you can't do anything from PHP to return it as a integer.

Answer (score 0):

I never needed something like this but if you really have to you can simply cast it using `+data`:

```
data = +data;
if (data === 1) {
     $('#results').html("Success");
} else if (data === 2) {
     $('#results').html("No Success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can pass boolean value instead of 0 or 1 i.e true or false from php